# Raspberry Pi B+ "no module named vlc"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc

I've installed the vlc player for raspberry and the vlc module for python on my b+ like this:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo pip install python-vlc
```

of course with update and even upgrade of the raspi.

But every time i try to

```
import vlc
```

in the python shell, i get the error "no module named 'vlc'"

has anyone an idea of a solution to this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: [This page](http://www.rukspot.com/How_to_install_LibVLC_on_Ubuntu.html) suggests you also need to install `libvlc-dev`. I can't try it out, sorry. See also [LibVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC)

Comment: thanks for the tip. Sadly it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: May I see the output of: `pip show vlc`. Verify if the showen package path is in your Python Sys path.

Comment: i solved the problem by myself: raspbian (jessie) has python 2.7 and 3.4 preinstalled at the same time and to install something for 3.4 version i have to use pip3. Otherways it will be installed on 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure no one misses the answer, since this fixed it for me:

OP mentioned this in the comments above:

> i solved the problem by myself: raspbian (jessie) has python 2.7 and 3.4 preinstalled at the same time and to install something for 3.4 version i have to use pip3. Otherways it will be installed on 2.7